# Doesn't generate the 'out' directory in Intellij

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I just switched to Intellij from Eclipse. I imported a maven project which is built from Eclipse. I tested running a class with a 'main()' method. I can see the 'target' is generated, but didn't see the 'out' directory. The tutorial says an 'out' directory will be generated. Is this optional or required?

Comment: It depends on the project type, for the Maven projects IntelliJ IDEA follows Maven guidelines for the source and output directories, therefore it will work the same like from the command line Maven.

Comment: so, it will be 'target' directory generated, right?

Comment: Yes, it will be `target`.